# Trying to control serialization of REST response dynamically based on HTTP parameters in spring-boot application

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

We have a Spring boot application that provides several REST APIs to Angular UI. We are hitting the performance problem in showing lists of things. Angular sends GET REST request to the back-end and gets the shallow list of elements. When UI shows the list, for each row it needs to load bunch of details, so it sends several requests per row. To show first page with 50 items it sends several hundreds of requests.
To optimize it, we need to be able to "enrich" the initial list request to include all that information. What children to include should be controlled by HTTP parameters of the initial request so that it would contain all information needed to display the list.

Something like: `?children=contacts&children=document&children=document.notes`

I was experimenting with different Jackson features. Views, Perspectives, JsonIgnore and other static ways would not help here. So I looked at filters and custom serializes. I managed to make it work somewhat, but...

I tried creating filters and serializers for each class (Case, Document, etc.) however, **serialization never goes "deeper" then the root object.**

I am relatively new with Spring-boot and Jackson.  I am running out of ideas.
In essence my code looks like this so far (I am sorry for so much details, but this is as a smallest extract I could do without loosing important pieces)

model class:

```
@JsonFilter("CaseFilter")
@Entity
public class Case implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "Case", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Document document;

    // ...
}

@JsonFilter("DocumentFilter")
@Entity
public class Document implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Case case;

    // ...
}
```

Then I created custom serializer for each model

```
public class ModelSerializationConfig {
    private String filterName;
    private String parameterPrefix;
    private Class modelClass;

    public ModelSerializationConfig(String filterName, String parameterPrefix, Class modelClass) {
        this.filterName = filterName;
        this.parameterPrefix = parameterPrefix;
        this.modelClass = modelClass;
    }

    public String getFilterName() {
        return filterName;
    }

    public String getParameterPrefix() {
        return parameterPrefix;
    }

    public Class getModelClass() {
        return modelClass;
    }
}
@JsonComponent
public class CaseSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Case> {

    public static ModelSerializationConfig CONFIG =
            new ModelSerializationConfig("CaseFilter", "case.", Case.class);

    @Autowired
    private FilteringSerializerService serializerService;

    @Override
    public void serialize(Case case, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException {
        serializerService.serialize(case, jsonGenerator);
    }
}

@JsonComponent
public class DocumentSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Document> {

    public static ModelSerializationConfig CONFIG =
            new ModelSerializationConfig("DocumentFilter", "case.document.", Document.class);

    @Autowired
    private FilteringSerializerService serializerService;

    @Override
    public void serialize(Document document, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException {
        serializerService.serialize(document, jsonGenerator);
    }
}
```

I have externalized serialization logic into separate service

```
@Component
public class FilteringSerializerService {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FilteringSerializerService.class);

    private final static String PARAMETER_NAME = "children";

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    private SimpleFilterProvider filterProvider;

    String[] childrenParam = null;

    private SimpleFilterProvider getFilterProvider() {
        if(filterProvider == null) {
            filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider();
        }
        return filterProvider;
    }

    private void initFilter(ModelSerializationConfig config) {
        CustomFilter filter = null;
        try {
            filter = (CustomFilter)getFilterProvider().findPropertyFilter(config.getFilterName(), null);
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            LOGGER.info("Need to add filter " + config.getFilterName());
            filter = new CustomFilter();
            getFilterProvider().addFilter(config.getFilterName(), filter);
        }
        filter.init(config, childrenParam);
    }

    private void initFilters() {
        initFilter(Case.CONFIG);
        initFilter(DocumentSerializer.CONFIG);
    }

    public void serialize(Object object, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator) throws IOException {
        childrenParam = httpServletRequest.getParameterValues(PARAMETER_NAME);
        LOGGER.info("service serialize called");

        LOGGER.info("filter params specified. Needs filtering {}", object.getClass().getSimpleName());
        initFilters();

        LOGGER.info("Creating mapper");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setFilterProvider(getFilterProvider());
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

        LOGGER.info("Mapping");
        String result = mapper
                .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                .writeValueAsString(object);

        // Strip {} of the object
        result = result.substring(1, result.length() - 2);

        LOGGER.info("Writing");
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeRaw(result);
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

And finally custom filter looks like this

```
public class CustomFilter implements PropertyFilter {

    public void init(ModelSerializationConfig config, String[] childrenParam) {
    // Accept config and HTTP parameters here...
    }

    protected boolean shouldInclude(Object pojo, String name) {
    // Filtering logic...
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider prov, PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {
        if(shouldInclude(pojo, writer.getName())) {
            writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, prov);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeAsElement(Object elementValue, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider prov, PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {
        writer.serializeAsElement(elementValue, jgen, prov);
    }

    @Override
    public void depositSchemaProperty(PropertyWriter writer, ObjectNode propertiesNode, SerializerProvider provider) throws JsonMappingException {
        writer.depositSchemaProperty(propertiesNode, provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void depositSchemaProperty(PropertyWriter writer, JsonObjectFormatVisitor objectVisitor, SerializerProvider provider) throws JsonMappingException {
        writer.depositSchemaProperty(objectVisitor, provider);
    }
}
```

At this point I am actually questioning this entire thing. I suspect that there is a more elegant solution for this problem out there. I just can't find it.

Thanks.

Comment: what looks like you are trying to implement is `GraphQL`, i don't think we can help without more details on what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: How about you populate only required fields from the database and leave everything else as null?  Then you can use a custom mapper for serialization before returning. `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  mapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);`